# Form that was specified to be the MdiParent for this form is not an MdiContainer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mdi, mdichild

I was working on an inventory software and suddenly  came to know that I need some main form through which I should open all the other forms, so I created one named frmMainPanel and use a menu strip to link it to another I am successful in linking them but they are opening outside the main form, I use following code to link them

Linking frmSaleInvoice form using:

```
frmSaleInvoice childForm = new frmSaleInvoice();
cs.show()
```

now i realize i should make them child to the main form so i tried that using following code:

```
frmSaleInvoice childForm = new frmSaleInvoice();

childForm.MdiParent = this;
childForm.Show();
```

but it says `**" Form that was specified to be the MdiParent for this form is not an MdiContainer."**`

can any one help me out wher i am mistaking and how could i make a form named frmSaleInvoice to child of other form named frmMainPanel

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The Mdi parent must have it's [`IsMdiContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.ismdicontainer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property set to `True`. You can set this property at design time in your `frmMainPanel` form.

Comment: I already set the IsMdiContainer property to true, but the error is still persisting.

Comment: @Pratikk I feel silly for asking but you did set `IsMdiContainer` to `true` for the *PARENT* form?

Comment: What if the Main Form isMDIContainer and still thrown error?
Note: My MainForm Loads Forms from FormManager Class

Answer (score 9):

You should set the `IsMdiContainer = true` for the parent form.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to set the `childForm` to true, you can
try this:

```
childForm.MdiParent = (name of your mdiparent form).ActiveForm;
childForm.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write `IsMdiContainer = true;` in your code.

```
Form2 fL = new Form2();
fL.MdiParent = this;
fL.Show();
```

`Form2` is the name of the form that you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void tsbCadastrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            frmCliente cliente = null;
            foreach (Form frm in this.MdiChildren)
            {
                if (frm is frmCliente)
                {
                    cliente = (frmCliente)frm;
                    break;
                }
            } 
            if (cliente == null)
            {
                cliente = new frmCliente();
                cliente.MdiParent = this; //Remove this line in case the IsMdiParent = True 
                cliente.Show();
            }
            cliente.Focus();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Não foi possivel se conectar ao formulario devido ao erro: " + ex.Message,
                "Aviso",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hope it´s usefull

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.